# Getting Child type in base class to pass as type parameter to another method

Tags: c#, types, unity-game-engine

I have a base class called `Powerup` and 2 descendent classes `Bomb` and `Repel`.

I have a method that needs to get called where I pass the object type as a parameter.

```
public void PowerupExpired<T>() where T : Powerup {
    //do stuff here
}
```

Is there any way from the base class `Powerup` I can get the child class type and pass it to the method? I cannot use Generic types. The type I pass to the method has to be of type `Powerup`

Right now, I am getting around by in the `Powerup` class using:

```
if (this is BombPowerup)
   PowerupManager.PowerupExpired<BombPowerup>();
else if (this is RepelPowerup)
   PowerupManager.PowerupExpired<RepelPowerup>();
//etc etc
```

Though this isn't neat or extensible.

EDIT:

I forgot to add. The reason I cannot have Generic Types is because I am going on to use the Unity `GetComponent<T>()` method using the parameter type pass through in `PowerupExpired`, which does not accept generic types.

Comment: Difficult to say without seeing your entire architecture, but it seems like you should ditch the generic method, pass in the base class and then do whatever you need to do with a virtual method in BombPowerup and RepelPowerup. Is there a reason why you can't do this?

Comment: No I suppose there isn't. Will wait to see what the other answers are, but this might be the solution. Thanks

Comment: Why do you want to use a generic method in the first place? You don't pass any parameters to it and don't return anything.
The only information you get from defining a generic method here is a type. But then you could just use a parameter and pass it with `this.GetType()`.

Comment: I wanted to use a generic method because I end up using a unity method GetComponent<Type>()

Comment: PowerupManager need to know the concrete type in order to handle the powerup right? IF yes then create different overload of PowerupExpired method, each for each type. If no, than it must be able to process whatever powerup received as arguments, and you still don't need generics but you can rely on the base class type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your only reason for having the generic method is to use the generic unity method, don't use the generic unity method.

There is an alternative method [`GetComponent(Type t)`](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/GameObject.GetComponent.html) where you pass in the type (it's actually more robust, you can, for example, pass in interfaces instead of classes that inherit from component).

Your code would looking (something like):

```
public void PowerupExpired(PowerUp p)
{
    PowerUp powerUpComponent = GetComponent(p.GetType());
}
```

where

```
class BombPowerup : Powerup
{}
```

and

```
class RepelPowerup : Powerup
{}
```

and presumably

```
class Powerup : Component
{}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like the following? I don't really understand what do you want exactly, but I gave it a shot.

Make Powerup an abstract class, just a base class for all other powerups.

```
public abstract class Powerup
{
    // common behaviour for all powerups       
}
```

Then every kind of a powerup will inherit from this base class.

```
public class BombPowerup : Powerup
{
    // specific behaviour
}
```

Declare PowerupExpired method so that it takes a parameter.

```
public void PowerupExpired<T>(T param) where T : Powerup
{
    // for example print a type of an argument
    Console.WriteLine(param.GetType().Name);
}
```

Try out.

```
PowerupExpired(new BombPowerup());
```

Answer (score 1):

From your code, it looks very much like you want to do different things in `PowerupExpired` Depending on whether it's a bomb or repel. So why not have two methods?